Hyperoctahedral group, preliminaries
I am looking for information on the hyperoctahedral group
From what I understand, the hyperoctahedral group is 'the generalized symmetric group' in the case where $m=2$. That is, the hyperoctahedral group = $S(2,n)$.
From what I see about the generalized symmetric group,
$S(1,n)$ permutes the set ${1, 2, 3, \cdots, n}$
ie $$S(1,n)= \hspace{.15cm}\langle(12),(23),\cdots,(n-1 \hspace{.2cm}n)\rangle,$$
It was my intuition that
$S(2,n)$ permutes the set $\{1_a, 2_a, 3_a, \cdots, n_a, 1_b, 2_b, 3_b, \cdots, n_b\}$
ie $$S(2,n)= \hspace{.15cm}\langle(12)_a,(23)_a,\cdots,(n-1\hspace{.2cm}n)_a, (12)_b,(23)_b,\cdots,(n-1\hspace{.2cm}n)_b\rangle$$
but was told this is not the case. Instead, $S(2,n)=\mathbb{Z}_2^n \rtimes S_n$. How then is $S(2,n)$ isomorphic to the signed permutation group?
--Can someone give me some intuition on how this relates to the symmetries of octahedrons and their $n$-dimensional analogues? (For instance, we know that $S(2,n)=\mathbb{Z}_2^n \rtimes S_n$. Since there are 48 symmetries of the octahedron/cube, I assume this is $\mathbb{Z}_2^3\times S_3$ (ie n=3). How does this relate to the symmetries of the cube?)
-- We used the semi-direct product in our definition (which I have no experience with). Can I list the elements as I would have expected to with the direct product (ie $(\bar{0},\bar{1},\bar{0},(123)) \in S(2,3)$)?
-- Is it true that $S(2,3)=<(16),(35),(42),(13)(65),(14)(62),(45)(23)>$?

can anyone give a resource on hyperoctahedral groups? -- esp one that is a bit easy on the eyes. I'm really just looking for examples, possibly diagrams for very low n values.

Your question suggests you haven't calculated the group of symmetries of the cube before -- this is typically covered in any first course on group theory. You can learn about semidirect products by reading about them in any book on group theory; no doubt there are plenty of online notes as well. Mathoverflow is for research-level questions, so I'm voting to move your question to math.SE.

I'm writing a paper about coxeter groups. I know what the group of symmetries of the cube looks like. This is a much different approach that's part of a special example of coxeter groups.... I'm finishing up my master's and at no point did anyone talk about semi-direct products. I'm asking the question about semi-direct products because in this instance the generalized symmetric group is the wreath product. All in all, this was just a nice way to gain some understanding of semi-direct products, wreath products, coxeter groups and an alternate set of generators for the symmetry of the cube.

Moving the topic only serves to gatekeep. I guess my school isn't good enough for you, but this is for a research project in an MA degree. Generally people are nicer and more reasonable on this site, as opposed to math stack exchange, but clap clap, you've proved me wrong.

wow. thanks. you closed it?

@ness the intention is not to gatekeep, but to avoid MO being a free-for-all on undergrad mathematics. We don't always get the level right. I don't think this question should have been closed, and it is borderline between an exercise one could ask non-grad students to do, and something that comes up in someone's research (as it has in this case). There is nothing about your school (we know nothing about that, or even what country you are in) in this. But if experienced mathematicians recognise this a question on the level of a coursework exercise, then they might be right.

In saying I don't think this question should have been closed, it sits in that awkward place where it can sometimes survive or otherwise here on MO, and certainly would have done ok at math.SE. In cases like these, highlighting the research origin of the question can help, as well as pointing out where it is intended to be used. Other than that, I'm sorry you felt ill-used. I hope down the line we can put this behind us, and MO can only improve in the future, making it more useful for you.

The hyperoctahedron has $n$ diagonals between opposite vertices, let's number them from $1$ to $n$, and name the vertices of the $i$-th diagonal $+i$ and $-i$ (arbitrarily).
What are the permutations $\sigma$ of the vertices that corresponds to isometries of the hyperoctahedron? The key observation is that opposite vertices are send to opposite vertices, so $\sigma(-i)=-\sigma(i)$. Other than that, there are no restriction: one can permute the diagonals as we want (this gives the $S_n$ factor), and then flip them independently (this gives the $\mathbb Z_2^n$ factor). In short, the hyperoctahedral group consists of all permutations $$\sigma\colon\{\pm 1,\pm 2,\ldots,\pm n\}\to\{\pm 1,\pm 2,\ldots,\pm n\}$$ such that $\sigma(-i)=-\sigma(i)$.

This group is isomorphic to the symmetries of the hypercube (of the same dimension). It just follows from the fact that hypercube and hyperoctahedron are dual. (If you pick a vertex at the center of each facet of an hypercube, you get an hyperoctahedron, and reciprocally.) So isometries of the hypercube coincide with isometries of the hyperoctahedron.

Indeed, one can list the elements as for the direct product (as a set, the semi-direct product is the cartesian product), however the composition is different. (See definition of semi-direct products.)



amazing.
yeah ive been trying to work out those elements of order 3 - ive been looking at the octa hedron; vertice 1 on top, vertices 2,3,4,5 in the middle (clockwise) and vert 6 on the bottom. Those 3 cycles are (125)(346), (145)(236), and (314)(256).

is it true that the swapping of opposite vertices (call them 1&6, 2&4, 3&5) and the permutations of these elements (our s_3) generate this group?

like does $S(2,3)=<(16),(35),(42),(13)(65),(14)(62),(45)(23)>$

@ness To see how a $3$-cycle works, lay your octahedron on one of its faces, and then rotate it by $2\pi/3$ about its now-vertical axis.
